# Cubic Spline with average data observation in Python

Tags: python

I have quarterly observations like the following:

> date             y
>
> 2000-03-31     4.03333
>
> 2000-06-30    3.93333
>
> 2000-09-30     4.0
>
> 2000-12-31     3.9
>
> 2001-03-31     4.23333
>
> 2001-06-30    4.4
>
> 2001-09-30    4.83333
>
> 2001-12-31    5.5
>
> 2002-03-31    5.7
>
> 2002-06-30    5.83333
>
> 2002-09-30    5.73333
>
> 2002-12-31    5.86667

I want to convert it to monthly basis in use of cubic spline function. The problem is that those observations in my data are quarterly average, say, 4.03333 is the average of the observations in 2000-01-31, 2000-02-29 and 2000-03-31 etc. The resulting cubic spline curve should capture this property. I mean if the cubic spline curve is `$y=f(date)$`, then `$f$` should satisfy:

$$\frac{f(2000-01-31)+f(2000-02-29)+f(2000-03-31)}{3}=4.03333.$$

And

$$\frac{f(2000-04-30)+f(2000-05-31)+f(2000-06-30)}{3}=3.93333.$$

etc.,

I don't find scipy.interpolate has such functions can do that. Is there someone can tell me that whether this is possible in Python. I know how to do this in SAS.

Thanks!

Sorry for those math symbols, because I can not post images for those equations.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following function in Pandas where `func` would expect an array of size `window`, with which you can do your interpolation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.rolling_window.html